# Suggestion for latex command to reproduce as in the attached picture

Tags: header-footer, margins, titles

How do I get text above the top margin, specifically like in the picture attached below?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Which document class do you use? Should the header be on every page or only on the first one?

Comment: @samcarter I usually use amsart documentclass for research article. But I guess for statement of purpose, article documentclass would also do. The header will be in the first page only. It's like enlarged footnote, but above the top margin. Maybe it is possible to do it manually but I don't know how to do it above the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to simply add this information manually to your document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{text}
\author{names}
\date{text}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Name:}

\textbf{Program:}

\textbf{University:}

\hrulefill

{
\let\newpage\relax
\maketitle
}
text

\end{document}
```

[image]